# Balanced weight perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory, open-problem, matching-theory

Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, edge weight $w_e \ \forall e \in E$, I'm interested in the following problem.

Find a perfect matching $M \subseteq E$ that minimizes $(\max_{e \in M} w_e - \min_{e \in M} w_e)$.

Does this problem generalize/reduce to an existing problem? I can find [max weight perfect matching](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~naveen/courses/CSL851/lec4.pdf), but not exactly a "balanced weight perfect matching". Any thoughts would be helpful.